# Deploy an Azure Virtual Machine Scale Set and install IIS with multiple web sites from VSTS

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I want the following:

- An autoscaling VMSS deployed with an ARM template
- IIS Installed
- The default web site installed from one VSTS repository (which has a CI build)
- A web site from another VSTS repository installed at a virtual path (a sub web site contained within the default web site. (which has it's own CI build)

I have tried a heap of different release pipeline options but just cannot quite get there.

I can get an autoscaling VMSS deployed with an ARM template by copying a basic template from the starter guides or by manually deploying a VMSS in the Azure Portal and then downloading the ARM templates, hosting them in a VSTS repository and using the Release pipeline ARM deployment task to create/update the Azure Resource Group containing the VMSS.

I can get a successful build working on a single VM using a deployment group but VMSS's are not able to be part of a deployment group. ([see this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/7550))

The issues seem to come in when I want to actually deploy the web sites I have built to the scale set. The two options I seem to have come across are using the Desired State Configuration Extension to run a PowerShell script that will have to install the AzureRM commandlets, then install the web sites by downloading the build artifacts and manually installing (or using Web Deploy) that I will have to upload to somewhere like blob storage or by creating a baked machine image that will probably run a very similar script to do the same thing.

What are my options? What is the simplest deployment path to follow? Am I missing another path to a simpler deployment?

As I have two web sites to install my release pipeline has multiple artifacts (Main Web Site CI build output, Sub Web Site CI build output, Deployment Scripts git repo).

Comment: so what exactly doesnt work

Comment: @4c74356b41 updated the question to provide more information (interesting username you have)

Comment: so vmss is not any different to a vm. except its a bunch of vms. I dont really understand the problem

Comment: @4c74356b41 On a single VM, you can install the Azure deployment agent and make it a part of a deployment group. The deploy step is then simple as the deployment runs on every machine in the deployment group. As a scale set changes the number of images there is no easy path to assign a machine as part of a deployment group or install the deployment agent on the machine. See the link to the issue in github for more information on this.

Answer (score 0):

For virtual machine scale sets to work you need to create a sysprepped image of the main VM once you have set it up.

Make sure you follow this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/

Comment: Thanks, as I want a continuous integration build this means that I have to build the image every time I deploy? I would like the main image to be one from the Microsoft VM image library, then deploy some windows services then the two web sites. Any advice on this?

Comment: Also in the guide creating the sysprepped image is a manual task, I want to do this in an automated fashion, not manually.

Comment: There are multiple ways to approach this, no direct VSTS/Azure Devops route, but here are some pointers: 1. You could use App Services, unless there is a specific need to use VM's that I am unaware of. With this option, you can do a full deploy using Azure DevOps. 2. If you have to use VM's, you can decouple it and run an ARM template everytime an alert kicks in? I don't think VM scale sets support your scenario as of today and my knowledge.

Comment: I have other things running with App Services, unfortunately what I am deploying relies on legacy code that I have to manually install onto a VM. In the future our code base will be updated and will not require it but at the moment it does. This means our only option is to run it onto a VM.

Comment: In that case I would do the following, 1. Create an availability set, add a single vm to it first, 2. Add an LB and configure the probes required for the application. "NOTE; Adding an availability set to VM's later is a long process so make sure you do it first. This is also true when associating an LB to an availability set, deploy all those using ARM 3. Deploy the application using Azure DevOps deployment groups to IIS and test 4. You can always scale up VM's an deallocate them for minimal/no-cost unless you are using managed disks, although I would recommend managed disks.

Answer (score 0):

there is no real way around the fact that you need vsts agents on the nodes, i believe. vsts doesnt yet support vmss as a deployment target. so you need to invent your own hacks. you could deploy to only 1 node of vmss (very first one, like a master). and use a simple script to sync data across nodes. you can use things like octopus, or create DSC configuration to pull data from some storage account (you could utilize MSI to make it less painful).

Either way you have to hack your way through.

ps. to me building images is the worst solution (even if automated)

Comment: Building images is a pain. I think that it is the only option left to me. Could you add some extra context about your experience, I think I will end up with a PowerShell Script run from an ARM template that uses a standard Azure Server 2016 image that then manually install the Azure Commandlets and from there do a manual install. I have spun up a Vm and am working my way through writing a PowerShell Script on that machine that I will use, once completed, that runs on every VM in the scale set either buy using DSC or the CustomScriptExtension, or both if that is possible.

Comment: what do you want to know